# Looping over group/subgroup/layers in OpenLayers v8.2.0

Tags: openlayers

How can I loop over layer groups/subgroups and print their ids (eg. title) in `console.log`? this seems to be not working:

```
map.getLayers().forEach(function(layer) {
  if(layer instanceof layer.LayerGroup) {
    layer.getLayers().forEach(function(groupLayer) {
      layer.textContent = myLayers;
      console.log(myLayers);
    });
  }
});
```

and this is the group/subgroup/layer structure:

```
const subgroup1 = new LayerGroup({
  title: 'sb1',
  fold: 'close',
  visible: false,
  layers: [
    new WebGLTileLayer({
      title: 'l1_sb1',
      style: bac,
      source: new GeoTIFF({
        sources: [{
          url: 'raster/xxx.tif',
          nodata: 0,
        }],
      }),
    }),
    new WebGLTileLayer({
      title: 'l1_sb2',
      style: bac,
      source: new GeoTIFF({
        sources: [{
          url: 'raster/xxx.tif',
          nodata: 0,
        }],
      }),
    }),
  ],
});

const subgroup2 = new LayerGroup({
  title: 'sb2',
  fold: 'close',
  visible: false,
  layers: [
    new WebGLTileLayer({
      title: 'l2_sb1',
      style: slo,
      source: new GeoTIFF({
        normalize: false,
        sources: [{
          url: 'raster/xxx.tif',
          nodata: 0,
        }],
      }),
    }),
    new WebGLTileLayer({
      title: 'l2_sb2',
      style: slo,
      source: new GeoTIFF({
        normalize: false,
        sources: [{
          url: 'raster/xxx.tif',
          nodata: 0,
        }],
      }),
    }),
  ],
});

const subgroup3 = new LayerGroup({
  title: 'sb3',
  fold: 'close',
  visible: false,
  layers: [
    new WebGLTileLayer({
      title: 'l1_sb3',
      style: tri,
      source: new GeoTIFF({
        normalize: false,
        sources: [{
          url: 'raster/xxx.tif',
          nodata: 0,
        }],
      }),
    }),
    new WebGLTileLayer({
      title: 'l2_sb3',
      style: tri,
      source: new GeoTIFF({
        normalize: false,
        sources: [{
          url: 'raster/xxx.tif',
          nodata: 0,
        }],
      }),
    }),
  ],
});

const analisis = new LayerGroup({
  title: 'analisis',
  fold: 'close',
  layers: [
    subgroup1,
    subgroup2,
    subgroup3,
  ],
});
```

Thanks in advance for any pointers,

Comment: It would be easier to uise map.getAllLayes() https://openlayers.org/en/v8.2.0/apidoc/module-ol_Map-Map.html#getAllLayers